# Why Goku's Ultra Instinct wasn't awakened in his battle with Broly?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

In the tournament of power, Goku was pushed to his limits several times, and he awakened Ultra Instinct Omen, and Mastered Ultra Instinct. But in the battle with Broly (in which I would assume he was pushed to his limits too, since

> not even with Vegeta was he able to defeat Broly in Super Saiyan Blue

He couldn't awaken Ultra Instinct, not even Omen Ultra Instinct, and in the new manga arc we see he was "Ultra Instinct-less" for several years. Why wasn't Goku's Ultra Instinct awakened in his battle with Broly?

Comment: I would recommend you edit your title so that it doesn't specifically mention Broly. As it stands, the title is a spoiler for the new Broly movie, which hasn't even released yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultra  Instinct Goku is the strongest iteration of Goku in the history of Dragon Ball. Goku with that power was capable of easily overwhelming a fighter who rivaled the power of a God of Destruction.
Secondly, this skill is something which is so difficult to master that not even Beerus, who is one of the strongest God of Destruction across the Multiverse has been able to master and Beerus has lived for thousands of years.

From the movie's perspective there are many reasons why Goku doesn't tap into UI,

- While Broly is undoubtedly strong, he definitely doesn't rival the might of Ultra Instinct Goku and having Goku use UI against Broly would be a bit ridiculous considering the fact that Ultra Instinct has been regarded as such a complex skill and having Broly go toe to toe with it wouldn't make sense.
- The movie obviously wanted to make Gogeta canon for the sake of pushing merchandise and to cater to fans and they decided to use the fusion route.
- Even from the Movie's perspective, Goku isn't pushed to the same extent he is against Jiren. While Broly does defeat SSJB Goku, Both, Vegeta and Goku instant transmission out of there and then spend time fusing and go back. When Goku had to fight Jiren, despite getting beaten up multiple times, he had to still get up and keep fighting and a lot more was at stake(Considering his entire universe was at stake), compared to the fight with Broly. So Goku wasn't technically pushed to the same extent as he was in the tournament.

Having Goku achieve Ultra Instinct would result in them having to bring out characters stronger than Ultra Instinct which is something the series doesn't want to yet. During the T.O.P, it was more or less implied Goku surpassed the Gods with his mastered UI while he went toe to toe with Jiren. It was stated in the narrative of the DBS Broly movie that while Goku was almost as strong as a God, Vegeta is trying to catch up. Hence, they brought an enemy comparable to a God of Destruction. It seems very likely that the series might resume and if it does, it is very possible that we might see Goku possibly attaining this transformation eventually while going up against a very powerful enemy in the series.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason Goku failed to become ultra instinct was because he tried to force it to awaken. In all the Dragon Ball episodes when he awakened ultra instinct he did not force it. Ultra instinct was like an "end game" transformation because he is always beat-up the point that he can barely stand before he can activate ultra instinct.

In the Broly movie he was super sayain god and for a second tried to force ultra instinct and he failed and was forced to turn to super sayain blue his 2nd most powerful form besides unmastered ultra instinct.

Answer (score 0):

Goku didn't go MUI due to the story of Broly Character. It wouldn't make sense for a mastered powerful and strongest form to go toe to toe with a character that has remarkable power. Also rumors say that Goku and Broly will meet again. Broly will have new forms. Goku is going to learn how to tap into the Sayian monkey form like SS4 and power witch Broly has in the movie. Only after Goku masters that form we will see MUI play out again. DBZ/DBS/DBGT are going to have due a lot more tying all the story's into one. DBZ HERO's will appear to have a lot more of crazy new characters and fighting though.